# Merge two datasets where one has extra column SAS: proc sql

Tags: sql, merge, dataset, sas

I am trying to merge two data sets with a lot of the same observations except one has a column more.
Dataset1 contains data for 20% of the observations and Dataset2 contains observations for the other 80% (+ one column extra). If i run the code below, I get 4037 observations when i merge the two datasets with 315 observation!

```
proc sql;
create table RateExposure as
select *
from Dataset1, Dataset2
where Dataset1.ID = Dataset2.ID
order by Dataset1.ID;
quit;
```

If I run

```
data newDataset;
merge Dataset1 Dataset2;
by ID;
run;
```

I only get observation for one of the datasets - how can this be?

Comment: Maybe for the first code there will be better to use `SELECT t1.*, t2.extra_column FROM Dataset1 AS t1, Dataset2 AS t2`? and see the result

Comment: It does not seem to work. I tried different variations but nothing gave the correct outcome.

Comment: Did you try to join the tables?

Comment: I am not sure which join I should perform. I tried union join but I wasn't right

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE result AS
SELECT t1.*, t2.extra_column
FROM Dataset1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Dataset2 AS t2 ON (t1.ID = t2.ID)
;
QUIT;
```